# Substring matching for multi property object in Twitter Typeahead

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

So the data looks like this before going into the substring matcher:

```
var datasource = [
{name: 'Activity One', id: '1'},
{name: 'Activity Two', id: '2'},
{name: 'Activity Three', id: '3'},
{name: 'Activity Four', id: '4'}
];
```

When it was a normal array of values

```
var datasource =  { 'Activity One', 'Activity Two',...
```

It was simple to use twitter typeahead to match correctly, but now that there are multiple properties, I am not sure about how the substring matcher is supposed to work.

This is how Initialize the typeahead:

```
$(control)
    .typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlight: true,
            minLength: 0
        },
        {
            displayKey: "name",
            name: "name",
            source: substringMatcher(datasource)
        });
```

Now, the string matches correctly [on the initial click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc2ti.png), but [can't match it anymore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XR2f.png) using the substring matcher.

Here is the substring matcher:

```
var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches = [];
    var substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
    $.each(strs,
        function (i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
            }
        });
    cb(matches);
};};
```

What do I need to change? I don't know how to refer to the *.name property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloodhound does substring matching. As for accessing the properties, use

```
var ds = datasource.map(function(o) { return o.name; });
```